# IP redirect Lets encrypt

Tags: networking, lets-encrypt

Here is Lets encrypt documentation regarding http validation:

"Our implementation of the HTTP-01 challenge follows redirects, up to 10 redirects deep. It only accepts redirects to “http:” or “https:”, and only to ports 80 or 443. It does not accept redirects to IP addresses. When redirected to an HTTPS URL, it does not validate certificates (since this challenge is intended to bootstrap valid certificates, it may encounter self-signed or expired certificates along the way)."

I did couple of things on this:

1. I enabled port 80 on my server and I am using Azure firewall before the server. On the azure firewall I configured DNAT rule that all incoming traffic to port 80 of firewall should be forwarded to server's 80 port.
   **Result**: I can see that certificate issued in this case.
2. I enabled port 443 on my server. On the azure firewall I configured DNAT rule that all incoming traffic to port 80 of firewall should be forwarded to server's 443 port.
   **Result**: I see that the result is negative and no certificate issued in this case.

I have few questions on these results:

1. According to sentence in documentation, "It does not accept redirects to IP addresses". Why does my 1st case worked?
   Isn't DNAT a ip redirect?
2. If it's not a redirect why my 2nd case failed?

Answer (score 3):

No, DNAT is not a redirect.

Redirect is a HTTP response of a format

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://other.location/of/the/resource
```

i.e. it is issued by the HTTP server and happens on the layer 7, the application layer. NAT happens on the network layer, 3; the programs which are communicating (HTTP client and HTTP server) don't have a clue it ever happened.

Why didn't worked port 443? Answer first, what you wanted to do by NATing the HTTP port 80 to the static SSL/TLS port 443? The server which is listening on the port 443 is usually configured to use SSL so first thing it expects to see a *SSL ClientHello* packet, but the client accessing the port 80 issues HTTP request right away.

**Tip:** NAT both ports, 80 to 80, 443 to 443. Make sure requests accepted on port 80 get redirected to *https://*something; there are plenty of manuals how to do that, including Certbot's own configuration master which should ask you if you want to install such a redirect.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am dumb. But 443 is just a port unless we configure it with tls. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just a port, yes. With a well known assigned service and a standard typical configuration of servers that are bound to it. When you are writing "https://server/", it connects to the server port 443, despite the fact you never told it the port number,

Comment: I wanted to say, yes, ports are just ports, but when you write `http://server`, it just starts plain HTTP protocol on port 80. If you set up server to listen plain HTTP on port 443, fine, then write `http://server:443/` or forward port 80 to 443 as you did and connect to port 80 using `http://server`, it'll work. But a *typical* and *default* server configuration for port 443 is not plain HTTP, it's a static TLS, and the servers configured that way typically don't recognize the plain HTTP. Again, if you were trying `https://server:80`, it might have been worked with redirect, but why doing it?